# Is Background Intelligent Transfer Service responsible for Client Side Caching in Windows 7?

Tags: folder-redirection, offline-files

I'm reading documentation about [Configuring Offline Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633429(v=ws.10).aspx) and it keeps mentioning a background sync service, but doesn't tell you what it is called!!!  Is the service called `Background Intelligent Transfer Service`?  It's the closest thing I could find in `services.msc`

Comment: I don't have documentation link yet... You can set BITS to "disabled" and see that Offline Files still sync without issue.  Additionally, the "Offline Files" service does not have BITS marked as a dependency.